# How to pass values from to a "FormBuilderChipOption" to a SQFLITE database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, forms, sqflite

I have a series of "FormBuilderFilterChips" in a "ModalBottomSheet." The user should be able to press one or more options, and then a value - either text or a binary "0" or "1" - should be passed to the database. Hopefully any time the ModalBottomSheet is opened for editing, the previously selected values will be displayed.

So far I have tried several variations on "onPressed" and "onSelected," with no success.

Any ideas?

```
                      FormBuilderChipOption(
                        value: 'iBeginner',
                        avatar: CircleAvatar(child: Icon(Icons.theater_comedy_outlined)),
                        child: Text('Beginner'),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onChanged: _onChanged,
                    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                      FormBuilderValidators.minLength(1),
                    ]),
```

I also need to create something like a "TextEditingController" to send the selected values to the sqlHelper...